# full Screen mouse wheel scroll causes white

Tags: html, css

I made a full screen website and it has a wrapper which holds the content in a 1170pixels block.

The wrapper is centered.

When i try to make a full screen background with width 100% it works fine when i use it on my desktops full size.

But if i re-size the screen and then use the horizontal scroll bar or the mouse wheel all the backgrounds don't show up only what was visible when i resized the page.

I have tried to put 100% width for the body but it is not working at all. Same is happening on both mobile and tablet devices.

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: `<div class="black-bg">`
    `<h3> text </h3>`
`</div>`

`.blac-bg{`
`width:100%;`
`background-color:#333;`
`}` @jmore009

Comment: Update = It seems to work without the "width:100%;" but i need this for something else, anyone know what the cause might be

Answer (score 0):

width:100%;
Takes the width of the screen as it is when you open the site if you only want to make a background why not use this:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: `width: 100%` does NOT take the width of the screen as it was when the page was opened. Rather, the actual width is re-computed to be the window's width whenever the window changes size.